# How harmful would it be to the spine if you were sleeping on a soft rug for a prolonged period of time?

Tags: lasting-effects-duration, back, position, texture

If you were sleeping on a soft rug for a prolonged period of time, how detrimental would it prove to your back? I read somewhere that it is not advisable to sleep on a soft rug for a long period of time. This may cause potentially severe back and spinal problems later in life.

What are the recommended remedies?